# PC is lagging when I run Android Studio on Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, hardware, performance, android-studio

Why is my PC is lagging on Ubuntu 16.04 as compared to Windows 10 on the same computer when I run Android Studio? Is it due to lack of RAM?

System specs:

- CPU: Intel Core i3-5005U @ 2.00GHz
- RAM: 4GB

Results of `watch -n 5 free -m` :

[image: watch -n 5 free -m]

Results of `top` :

[image: top]

Comment: Looks like your system is swapping, so either lack of RAM or too many RAM-hungry applications open at once.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks. Actually about 1GB of RAM was being used by chrome extensions and lot of tabs (which I haven't thought of) that I had opened which was the main cause of lagging in ubuntu than windows.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended amount of RAM for running Android Studio in Ubuntu is 8GB, and your computer has only 4GB of RAM. You should expect to get not better than minimal performance from hardware that meets only the minimal requirements for Android Studio, and you should expect to get recommended performance from hardware that meets the recommended requirements.

According to the results of `top` the Ubuntu is using a lot of swap memory and Google Chrome is using a lot of hardware resources. This may be caused by having a lot of tabs opened simultaneously or by one or more installed Chrome extensions, especially if there are multiple Chrome extensions installed.